# how to design sigma(std) vector to have values above > 0 in VAE autoencoder

Tags: neural-network, autoencoder

I am trying to understand how to design mu and sigma vector in VAE autoencoder, as we know std value can not be larger than 0. If I use linear function, the value can be lower than zero, so I think Relu is the only activation function to apply in order to get sigma (Std) vector larger than zero. Would this be correct understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, almost, except that Relu might cause problems ones it goes to zero (having zero variance is a little odd and the gradient goes to zero as well). Usually you'd go with

$$ \sigma = \exp(\rho) $$

where $\rho$ is coming from the encoder.